# How to numerically integrate vector data in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have vector data `rdata` and `rho`. Each is a 641 x 1 vector, and `rho` is a function of `rdata`. I want to integrate rho(rdata)*2*pi*rdata from 0 to rmax. When I do the following, however, I get "NaN" for the result. Am I setting this up incorrectly? Is there a better way to numerically integrate vector data in Matlab?

```
% turn data into function
fr = @(r)interp1(rdata,rho,r);

% integrate
h = integral(@(r)fr(r)*2*pi*r,0,35.8,'ArrayValued',true);
```

---

**UPDATE**

I found out about the `trapz` function and tried the following

```
dens = 2*pi*rho.*rdata;
trapz(rdata,dens)
```

and obtained a value around 2.5, which is about two orders of magnitude lower than I expected. Am I implementing it incorrectly? `rdata` has nonuniform spacing, if that matters.

Comment: Use `.*` in the call to `integral`, and don't use the `'ArrayValued'` argument.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Do you mean something like `h = integral(@(r)fr(r).*2*pi*r,0,35);`? But when I do that I get an error using `*`.

Comment: `h = integral(@(r)fr(r).*2.*pi.*r,0,35);` (technically only the last one needs this, multiplication is left to right, so the first two are vector times scalar, the third one is vector times vector, but it doesn't hurt to put it everywhere where you don't mean matrix multiplication).

Comment: @CrisLuengo Hm, thanks, but I still get "NaN" for the result. I'm attaching a Dropbox link for the data in case it would help to see them directly: https://www.dropbox.com/s/318dwk7xb662c6b/Workbook2.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: About 2.5 is the correct value with the numbers you have. Calculate this `dens`, and you see its values are all below 1, most are about 0.1, give or take a bit. Difference between the first and last element of rdata is a bit below 35. Multiplying these two together, you expect value close to 3.5 or so.

Comment: You can also use something like `Fx = nansum(diff(x).*y(1:end-1))` where y = f(x). So if your function is not defined everywhere the nan value will be ignored.

Comment: Or to be a little bit more precise, `Fx = nansum(diff(x).*0.5.*(y(2:end)+y(1:end-1)))`

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55246914/8239061